# How to use a class (with list of classes) as a database with Create/Index Actions using MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5

I am currently on a MVC5 Project with databases and I got stuck.
I tried **alot** of things but none of it worked how I want.
I have a class (which fields are two lists of two other classes) which I want to use to recognize the current `UserName` (scroll down to see the class) and then use the specific lists of `IconModel` and `WindowModel`.

What I need:
I have two classes:

```
public class WindowModel
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Picture { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public WindowModel() { }

    public WindowModel(string picture, string title, string content)
    {
        Picture = picture;
        Title = title;
        Content = content;
    }
}
```

and

```
public class IconModel
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Left { get; set; }
    public int Top { get; set; }
    public string Picture { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }

    public IconModel() { }

    public IconModel(int left, int top, string picture, string text)
    {
        Left = left;
        Top = top;
        Picture = picture;
        Text = text;
    }
}
```

And finally a class that combines the two (for connecting/using) the database:

```
public class DataModel
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public List<WindowModel> Windows { get; set; }
    public List<IconModel> Icons { get; set; }

    public DataModel() { }

    public DataModel(string userName, List<WindowModel> windows, List<IconModel> icons)
    {
        UserName = userName;
        Windows = windows;
        Icons = icons;
    }
}

public class DataDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<DataModel> Data { get; set; }
}
```

I have a controller with Entity Framework with Create/Index/Edit/etc Actions.
My problem is now that in the Index Action I can use foreachs and access all data from the `List<WindowModel>` and `List<IconModel>`. But how can I use them in the Create Action? 
I can't use `@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Windows.Picture)` because it's a `List<>` (of course).  How can I have now EditorFors for every property (Windows.Picture, Windows.Title etc) of WindowModel/IconeModel?

What I have also tried is creating two databases (`DbSet<WindowModel> Windows` amd `DbSet<IconModel>`) but this didn't work properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a for loop, the data automatically gets serialized.

```
@for(int i = 0; i< x.Windows.Count(); i++)
{
   @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Windows[i].Picture)
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a more specific example please, because I don't want to loop through all Windows[i].Picture(s), I just need one EditorFor..

Comment: I guess you can send a  list with a single empty element to the view. or just do it once and copy the html it generates back to the view.